# Variável global usada em várias funções

Tags: python, funções, variáveis, escopo-de-variáveis

Eu tenho este código:

```
donos=[]
def calcula_media():

    lista_dicionario= [1,2,3]
    donos.extend(lista_dicionario)

def funcao2():

    print donos
```

Como posso fazer para usar a variável global na 2º função usando o que usei na 1º para lhe fazer o `extend`, ou seja, obter o [1,2,3] na 2º função?

Comment: Existe algum problema? A melhor resposta que posso te dar é não fazer isto. Evite globais.

Comment: Sim , eu tenho uma função ( a 1º ) que permite obter uma lista de dicionario, que já consegui e a 2º que transforma essa lista de dicionario obtida num ficheiro CSV , que tambem sei como se faz , só nao sei é como ir buscar a lista da 1º funçao para  a 2º

Comment: Não estou vendo problema algum, está fazendo o que você diz querer.

Comment: Não , na 2º função donos é uma variavel vazia nao sei porque

Comment: http://ideone.com/z5rSkv

Comment: o que é que  a linha 9 e 10 fazem ?

Comment: Chama as funções, sem chamar não executa

Comment: É isso mesmo já deu , valeu :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que entendi só faltava chamar as funções:

```
donos = []
def calcula_media():
    lista_dicionario = [1,2,3]
    donos.extend(lista_dicionario)

def funcao2():
    print(donos)

calcula_media()
funcao2()
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MsjFns). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gednzpxf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/GlobalVariable.py).

Idealmente em código real em aplicação complexa, o melhor a fazer é não usar variáveis globais assim e sempre passar como argumento.